# How to split a spark dataframe column string?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
|--------------------------------------|---------|---------|
|   path                                         |  content|  
|------------------------------------------------|---------|
|    /root/path/main_folder1/folder1/path1.txt   |   Val 1 |      
|------------------------------------------------|---------|
|    /root/path/main_folder1/folder2/path2.txt   |   Val 1 |      
|------------------------------------------------|---------|
|    /root/path/main_folder1/folder2/path3.txt   |   Val 1 |      
|------------------------------------------------|---------|
```

I want to split the column values in path by "/" and get the values only until /root/path/mainfolder1
The Output that I want is

```
|--------------------------------------|---------|---------|---------------------------|
|   path                                         |  content|  root_path                |
|------------------------------------------------|---------|---------------------------|
|    /root/path/main_folder1/folder1/path1.txt   |   Val 1 |  /root/path/main_folder1  |    
|------------------------------------------------|---------|---------------------------|
|    /root/path/main_folder1/folder2/path2.txt   |   Val 1 |  /root/path/main_folder1  |    
|------------------------------------------------|---------|---------------------------|
|    /root/path/main_folder1/folder2/path3.txt   |   Val 1 |  /root/path/main_folder1  |    
|------------------------------------------------|---------|---------------------------|
```

I know that I have to use withColumn split and regexp_extract but I am not quiet getting how to limit the output of regexp_extract.

What is it that I have to do to get the desired output?

Comment: what is the logic behind the `root_path` column? Take the first 3 directories?

Comment: @werner yup take the first three directories

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regular expression to extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) the first three directory levels.

```python
df.withColumn("root_path", F.regexp_extract(F.col("path"), "^((/\w*){3})",1))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------+
|path                                     |content|root_path              |
+-----------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------+
|/root/path/main_folder1/folder1/path1.txt|val 1  |/root/path/main_folder1|
|/root/path/main_folder1/folder2/path2.txt|val 2  |/root/path/main_folder1|
|/root/path/main_folder1/folder2/path3.txt|val 3  |/root/path/main_folder1|
+-----------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: This gives me a blank column in root_path

Comment: @RoshanJoeVincent does your data start with spaces? This would explain why you have to remove the `^`.